# Change to bold repeated text in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write some code that will look in an excel cell find if it contains the word that I am looking for and make it bold. I have written the following code so far

```
With Worksheets("Label Print").Cells(i, J)
.Characters(Start:=InStr(.Value, “Name”), Length:=Len(“Name”)).Font.Bold = True
End With
```

The issue is that if “Name” occurs twice (or more) in a cell it will highlight only its first occurrence.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function that takes the cell to check and the word to search for and bolds all cases of that word:

```
Public Sub BoldWord(rngCell As Range, sWord As String)

  Dim iPlace As Integer

  iPlace = InStr(1, rngCell.Value, sWord, vbTextCompare)
  Do While iPlace > 0
    rngCell.Characters(Start:=iPlace, Length:=Len(sWord)).Font.Bold = True
    iPlace = InStr(iPlace + 1, rngCell.Value, sWord, vbTextCompare)
  Loop

End Sub
```

Note 1: rngCell must be a single cell.

Note 2: the search is not case-sensitive... change vbTextCompare if necessary.

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Brilliant